# Como eu crio uma formatação customizada em uma string com angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, formatação

Bom eu tenho uma data 19102015, se eu fizer assim

```
{{step.data | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
```

eu consigo formatar a data e obtenho 19/10/2015.

Mas no meu caso eu preciso de algo customizado.
Tenho um cnpj que vem assim: 00000000000000 e preciso formatá-lo assim

```
00.000.000/0000-00
```

Alguem sabe me dizer como crio formações específicas com angularjs ?

Obrigado

Comment: Você não pode formatar com Jquery?

Comment: Oi @PauloHDSousa todo projeto já esta em angularjs, fazer em Jquery seria minha ultima opção. Obrigada

Comment: Você pode aplicar a mask `ui-br-cnpj-mask` no seu input com o angular-ui-inputs> https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks.

Comment: @EduardoSilva eu já aplico uma máscara,

<input ng-model="data.cnpj" type="tel" ui-mask="99.999.999/9999-99" ng-click="insereClass()" required> 

mas quando salvo ele não pega a máscara pega somente os números

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você esta procurando no AngularJS se chama `filter`.

Um `filter` pega um valor de input e parâmetros opcionais de configuração, e retorna um valor que será efetivamente exibido na interface.

Um `filter` é criado do seguinte modo:

```
angular.module('MeuModulo', []).filter('nomeDoFiltro', function() {
    return function(input, arg1, arg2) {
        var out;
        // manipula input e seus argumentos...
        return out;
    };
});
```

Por exemplo, um filtro que transforma uma string em `uppercase` quando parâmetro é `true`, e em `lowercase` quanado o parâmetro é `false`:

```
angular.module('MeuModulo', []).filter('case', function() {
    return function(input, uppercase) {
        var out = "";
        if ( uppercase ) {
            out = input.toUpperCase();
        } else {
            out = input.toLowerCase();
        }
        return out;
    };
});
```

Este filtro, pode então ser utilizado no seu HTML:

```
<p>{{ 'minha string' | case:true }}</p>
```

Ecoando após processado pelo AngularJS:

```
<p>MINHA STRING</p>
```

Veja mais sobre a criação de filtros na documentação do AngularJS:

[Developer Guide: Filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

*Criar o filtro para o CNPJ fica como exercício!*

Comment: minha única dúvida agora é como aplicar isso dentro do meu escopo. Eu consegui fazer um de exmplo,mas não consegui integrar com o meu projeto `var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.filter('cpf', function(){
    return function(cpf){
        return cpf.substr(0, 3) + '.' + cpf.substr(3, 3) + '.' + cpf.substr(6, 3) + '-' + cpf.substr(9,2);
    };
});` esse é o codigo que funciona.

Comment: Mas meu projeto usa $scope ai quando aplico não da certo `mainAppControllers.controller('MenuCtrl', ['myservice','$rootScope','$scope', '$routeParams', '$location',
    function(myservice,$rootScope,$scope, $routeParams, $location){`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/caumardegan/qgjfapyz/

Comment: @ClaudiaMardegan não entendi o problema... no Fiddle que você passou funcionou direitinho, estava tudo certo: na coluna com o atributo `ng-non-bindable` o filtro não foi aplicado, e na outra sem o atributo, o filtro foi aplicado certinho... veja o print: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ov99ybnetfqqkq/snapshot1.png?dl=0

Comment: Atualizei seu Fiddle com o filtro sendo utilizado em uma variável no serviço `$scope`. Veja se ajuda: http://jsfiddle.net/1yv9bnwL/